# Translation of "Get your ducks in a row"

Tags: перевод

I'm looking to translate "To get your ducks in a row". In English, this more or less translates into "To be fully prepared for something that is going to happen".

When I look for this in similar phrases the things I get back are more or less literal expressions like *Приведи свои дела в порядок*. However, I've also seen this *Так что выстраивай своих уточек* Is the latter phrase used much at all?

Would the following expression suffice?

*Едешь на день, хлеба бери на неделю*

Comment: please, don't add thanks at the end of your posts - it's redundant.

Comment: apart from the explanation, can you provide example(s) of usage if this phrase in English?

Comment: @shabunc "They should have had all their ducks in a row beforehand, so they were ready to start the job when required."

Comment: @shabunc I just considered it common courtesy if someone is going to answer my post I should thank them. I didn't think it was implied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found one more translation of the expression 'Get one’s ducks in a row. As for me it's ok in your context. In Russian it can mean 'собраться с мыслями, привести мысли в порядок'.To be translated litrally it sounds like 'put your thoughts in order' and means 'to analise the situation, to think a lot before doing somethung important'.

here's the link
https://set_expressions_en_ru.academic.ru/632/ducks_in_a_row

Answer (score 1):

It's a dictionary thing. “Get one’s ducks in a row” is heavily context-dependent, the main ways to say it in Russian being *собрать все силы*, *привести дела в порядок*, *подготовиться как следует*. Use the [Reverso Context online dictionary](https://context.reverso.net/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/ducks+in+a+row) to see word combinations / expressions / idioms used in sentences with translations.

Here is a way your example can be translated:

> They should have had all their ducks in a row beforehand, so they were ready to start the job when required. — Им следовало бы заранее как следует подготовиться, чтобы начать работу вовремя.

Comment: Do you generally find the Reverse Context site to be faithful for translations? I can't tell how it works and I know that some machine translations aren't great. It appears to use some form of crowdsourcing but beyond that, I can't tell.

Comment: @Banach - Yes, I think it's rather faithful, at least most of the sentence pairs are plausible. One of its pros is there are _many_ examples you can choose from, and also you can see how the phrase in question works, you see where you can vary, alter it.